# How to package styles with Angular2 components?

Tags: css, sass, angular

What's the recommended best practice to package styles with angular components? Before Angular 2, it was common to use sass/less to modularize a component/directive by keeping its styles in the same folder as the JavaScript and HTML. But at the end the build process would sweep the entire source and package all JavaScript into one file (e.g. bundle.js) and all css into one file (e.g. style.css). In other words, the JS and CSS were packaged separately even though they were in separate source modules. Is this still the recommended way in Angular 2 or something else?

Also, how does one account for global styles/themes? For example, if I am using some material design library or bootstrap, the components will definitely a dependency on those. Is there a concept of CSS dependencies?

Comment: I have written a tutorial which uses the [ng2-mean-webpack](https://github.com/datatypevoid/ng2-mean-webpack) starter kit. It demonstrates everything you are requesting to see. | http://www.davidniciforovic.com/2016/02/03/building-a-single-page-todo-app-with-mean-including-angular-2/

Comment: This is a perfectly valid question-

Answer (score 4):

Whatever styles you are using in your Angular 2 Components can from your global css you have referenced on the index.html that can be packages in the same way you have been doing before.

The Styles per component is only useful if you are building components that you want to export out to others to start using.

Even that you can reference a file and add it to a bundler.

```
@Component({
    selector: "my-app",
    templateUrl: './app/app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ["./app/app.css"]    
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
}
```

[Great blog for Styling on Angular2](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/06/25/styling-angular-2-components.html)